# Android ClassNotFoundException on source file in a different package

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I've managed to get a `NoClassDefFoundError` caused by a `ClassNotFoundException` by trying to access a class in a separate package.

I have written the code to reproduce this problem by pressing a button that calls the function below the stack traces.

What doesn't make any sense is that even though I have the source file in the project, it doesn't find the class.

Stack trace:

```
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/X(2517): x- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lobd/ObdGatewayService;
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517): xx- 
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lobd/ObdGatewayService;
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at piccolo.android.PANDA18.OBDTaximeter.doBindService(OBDTaximeter.java:856)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at piccolo.android.PANDA18.OBDTaximeter.startLiveData(OBDTaximeter.java:823)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at piccolo.android.PANDA18.OBDTaximeter.access$8(OBDTaximeter.java:818)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at piccolo.android.PANDA18.OBDTaximeter$3.onClick(OBDTaximeter.java:313)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20983)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "obd.ObdGatewayService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/piccolo.android.PANDA18-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/piccolo.android.PANDA18-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     ... 14 more
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: obd.ObdGatewayService
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):         ... 16 more
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: obd.ObdGatewayService
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):         ... 15 more
07-13 15:58:40.317: E/XX(2517):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Note that the above stacktrace is only produced for the first time I press the button. Subsequent button presses result in a shorter, slightly different version of it (See below).

```
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/X(32078): x- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: obd.ObdGatewayService
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078): xx- 
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: obd.ObdGatewayService
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078):    at piccolo.android.PANDA18.OBDTaximeter.doBindService(OBDTaximeter.java:856)
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078):    at piccolo.android.PANDA18.OBDTaximeter.startLiveData(OBDTaximeter.java:823)
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078):    at piccolo.android.PANDA18.OBDTaximeter.access$8(OBDTaximeter.java:818)
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078):    at piccolo.android.PANDA18.OBDTaximeter$3.onClick(OBDTaximeter.java:313)
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20983)
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
07-13 15:31:59.767: E/XX(32078):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Section of code that's causing the error:

```
// this is from the OBDTaximeter class, and is called whenever I press a specific button. I have a try/catch where I'm calling it to log the error above
private void doBindService() {
    if (!isServiceBound) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Binding OBD service..");
        if (preRequisites) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ObdGatewayService.class); // Specifically, this line
            bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        } else {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MockObdGatewayService.class);
            bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of solution explorer:

[image]

The yellow highlighted portion shows that the file is indeed in the same project, but in a different package, where the red line represents where the code that's trying to use the missing class is called.

I've considered that it may be a problem with my manifest declaration, but I can't find anything wrong with it - I may be wrong, so I'm including a condensed version containing the relevant bits below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="piccolo.android.PANDA18"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
        <activity android:name="OBDTaximeter" />

        <activity android:name="obd.ConfigActivity" />

        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="obd.MockObdGatewayService" />
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="obd.ObdGatewayService" />
    </application>  
</manifest>
```

I've also tried just cleaning and rebuilding (too many times to count). I made sure that the build path is correct (in terms of appcompat libraries, export order and whatnot), but just in case, I'm including a screenshot of the "Order and Export" screen from Eclipse below.

[image]

I've checked the classes.dex file, and I do find `ObdGatewayService` class listings inside it.

Listing of class in classes.dex:

```
Class #239            -
  Class descriptor  : 'Lobd/ObdGatewayService$1;'
  Access flags      : 0x0000 ()
  Superclass        : 'Ljava/lang/Object;'
  Interfaces        -
    #0              : 'Ljava/lang/Runnable;'
  Static fields     -
  Instance fields   -
    #0              : (in Lobd/ObdGatewayService$1;)
      name          : 'this$0'
      type          : 'Lobd/ObdGatewayService;'
      access        : 0x1010 (FINAL SYNTHETIC)
    #1              : (in Lobd/ObdGatewayService$1;)
      name          : 'val$job2'
      type          : 'Lobd/ObdCommandJob;'
      access        : 0x1012 (PRIVATE FINAL SYNTHETIC)
  Direct methods    -
    #0              : (in Lobd/ObdGatewayService$1;)
      name          : '<init>'
      type          : '(Lobd/ObdGatewayService;Lobd/ObdCommandJob;)V'
      access        : 0x10000 (CONSTRUCTOR)
      code          -
      registers     : 3
      ins           : 3
      outs          : 1
      insns size    : 8 16-bit code units
      catches       : (none)
      positions     : 
        0x0000 line=1
        0x0004 line=240
      locals        : 
        0x0000 - 0x0008 reg=0 this Lobd/ObdGatewayService$1; 
  Virtual methods   -
    #0              : (in Lobd/ObdGatewayService$1;)
      name          : 'run'
      type          : '()V'
      access        : 0x0001 (PUBLIC)
      code          -
      registers     : 3
      ins           : 1
      outs          : 2
      insns size    : 12 16-bit code units
      catches       : (none)
      positions     : 
        0x0000 line=243
        0x000b line=244
      locals        : 
        0x0000 - 0x000c reg=2 this Lobd/ObdGatewayService$1; 
  source_file_idx   : 4574 (ObdGatewayService.java)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you using Multidex or custom ProGuard rules?

Comment: Not using either one. @BladeCoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("obd", "obd.ObdGatewayService");
startService(intent);
```

Comment: Can you explain what the difference between your code and my code for starting an intent is? I'm very surprised that this avoids the problem, since all my other activities were starting using the format detailed in my code. While this is a hacky workaround to get rid of the exception, it doesn't solve the issue at hand.